# How to get details of selection from a drop-down list that was populated with JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have the following **test.json**:

```
{"countries":[{"countryCode":"US","officialName":"UNITED STATES OF AMERICA","continent":"NORTH AMERICA","currentSeason":"WINTER"},{"countryCode":"AR","officialName":"ARGENTINA","continent":"SOUTH AMERICA","currentSeason":"SUMMER"}]}
```

And the following html/jQuery that populates a dropdown with the `officialName` values from the JSON data:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
       <select id="countries"></select>
       <br>
       <textarea id="detailsbox" rows="4" cols="50">
       </textarea>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $select = $('#countries')
        $.getJSON('test.json',function(translations){
        $select.html('');
        //iterate over the data and append a select option
        $.each(translations.countries, function(key, val){ 
        $select.append('<option id="' + val.countryCode + '">' + val.officialName + '</option>');
       })
    });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

My question is, how can I access the other dependent data (like currentSeason, countryCode, continent) based on the country selected, and fill in the `detailsBox` textarea with that data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var translations = {
  "countries": [{
    "countryCode": "US",
    "officialName": "UNITED STATES OF AMERICA",
    "continent": "NORTH AMERICA",
    "currentSeason": "WINTER"
  }, {
    "countryCode": "AR",
    "officialName": "ARGENTINA",
    "continent": "SOUTH AMERICA",
    "currentSeason": "SUMMER"
  }]
}

var $select = $('#countries')
$.each(translations.countries, function(key, val) {
  $select.append('<option id="' + val.countryCode + '">' + val.officialName + '</option>');
})

$select.change(function() {
  var countrycode = $("option:selected",this).attr('id');

  $.each(translations.countries, function(key, val) {
    console.log(val.countryCode)
    console.log(countrycode)
    if(val.countryCode == countrycode)
    $("#detailsbox").text("season is " +val.currentSeason)
  })


}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="countries"></select>
  <br>
  <textarea id="detailsbox" rows="4" cols="50">
  </textarea>
</div>
```

1. use change event
2. on load fire change event of select

Comment: @ITWorker glad to help mate happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty using `Array.filter` to find the selected country after one is selected.

```
var $select = $('#countries');

// setting <option value="..."> as opposed to <option id="...">
$.each(translations.countries, function(key, val) {
    $select.append('<option value="' + val.countryCode + '">' + val.officialName + '</option>');
});

$select.change(function() {
    var code = $(this).val();
    var country = translations.countries.filter(function(value) {
        return value.countryCode == code;
    })[0];
    console.log(country);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative method.

Comment: No problem! One thing I noticed after the fact is that you were setting the `<option id="...">` attribute which won't get posted back to the server (and also breaks my solution).  I updated things to set `<option value="...">` which will post back to the server and also fixes my solution.

Comment: Thanks for the update! It was not my intention to post anything back to the server, as I am just practicing how to parse JSON data from simple GETs, but this will come in handy for the future.